# Displaying UTF characters in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I have a simple program, in which I need to display japanese characters. It has a bit strange behavour( in my opinion ), sometimes it displays character as it is, sometimes it displays it like square.

[image]

[image]

My program logic is initiate vector, that contains alphabet `InitAlphabet();` and then randomly choose a character `painter.drawStaticText(0, 0, alphabet[randomNumb]);`.

Can you pls tell why is this happening?
Code:

```
private:
    Ui::Widget *ui;
    QVector<QString> alphabet;
    QVector<QString> translation;
    int randomNumb;
```

---

```
void Widget::InitAlphabet()
{
    alphabet.push_back("あ");
    alphabet.push_back("い");
    alphabet.push_back("う");
    alphabet.push_back("え");
    alphabet.push_back("お");
    alphabet.push_back("か");
    alphabet.push_back("き");
    alphabet.push_back("く");
    alphabet.push_back("け");
    alphabet.push_back("こ");
    alphabet.push_back("さ");
    alphabet.push_back("し");
    alphabet.push_back("す");
    alphabet.push_back("せ");
    alphabet.push_back("そ");
    alphabet.push_back("た");
    alphabet.push_back("ち");
    alphabet.push_back("つ");
    alphabet.push_back("て");
    alphabet.push_back("と");
    alphabet.push_back("な");
    alphabet.push_back("に");
    alphabet.push_back("ぬ");
    alphabet.push_back("ね");
    alphabet.push_back("の");
    alphabet.push_back("は");
    alphabet.push_back("ひ");
    alphabet.push_back("ふ");
    alphabet.push_back("へ");
    alphabet.push_back("ほ");
    alphabet.push_back("ま");
    alphabet.push_back("み");
    alphabet.push_back("む");
    alphabet.push_back("め");
    alphabet.push_back("も");
    alphabet.push_back("や");
    alphabet.push_back("ゆ");
    alphabet.push_back("よ");
    alphabet.push_back("ら");
    alphabet.push_back("り");
    alphabet.push_back("る");
    alphabet.push_back("れ");
    alphabet.push_back("ろ");
    alphabet.push_back("わ");
    alphabet.push_back("ん");
}
```

---

```
int Widget::getRandomNumber()
{
    return qrand() % alphabet.length();
}

void Widget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.drawStaticText(0, 0, alphabet[randomNumb]);
   // painter.drawStaticText(50, 50, translation[randomNumb]);
}
```

---

Comment: Show more code. In particular, what is `alphabet`, and what does `InitAlphabet()` look like?

Comment: Your font doesn't have that character so the widget cannot display it. Just a guess. There is zero information about your characters and which of them can and cannot be displayed.

Comment: Put the actual code that sets the widget's text or paints the text.

Comment: Put. Before minusing pls give some sense in comments , cause random minusing is so cool. Btw painting all painting code was already on the question.

Comment: Try to push the items like :  `alphabet.push_back(QString::fromStdWString(L"た"));`

Comment: Another idea is to try and print the characters you display to a text file, in UTF-8. Then compare the file with what you see on screen.

Comment: Tried thing @Nejat suggested, still have same output, some are squares and some are oks.

Comment: Also try bypassing the logic and showing all the characters in a single QString.

Comment: @n.m. Tried both variants, first program prints out all characters without any squares, second changed it to QString, but nothing changed.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by "nothing changed". Have you tried something like `painter.drawStaticText(0, 0, QString("あいうえおかきくけこさしすせそたちつてとなにぬねのはひふへほまみむめもやゆよらりるれろわん"));`? What was the result?

Comment: It prints all characters ok.

Comment: I tried String::fromUtf8, or just QString("\u..."), sometimes it shows the same character, sometimes not and it's very strange.

Comment: To be more precise when I do `painter.drawStaticText(0, 0, QString("あいうえおかきくけこさしすせそたちつてとなにぬねのはひふへほまみむめもやゆよらりるれろわん"));` One time it prints all chars, another time it just shows square.

Comment: Well I have never managed to reproduce any such behaviour, see [full working example here](http://pastebin.com/UQLjAKK1). You probably have a bug elsewhere. Start throwing away code until the bug disappears.

Comment: It seems now funny, tried the same code just running on Windows and it works ok :P. Sorry to bother you.